# Is there a way to specify hard drives mounting order in kvm/qemu?

Tags: qemu, kvm

At the moment I am adding drives to my vm like this:

```
kvm ... -drive file=WindowsOS.img,format=raw -drive file=/dev/sdb -drive file=data.img
```

So the first drive is preconfigured OS, second drive is formatted `ntfs` drive with single partition, third is some dynamically generated content. And I want those to be mapped precisely in this order as `C`, `D`, `E`. But for some reasons `data.img` becomes drive `D` here and `ntfs` drive `/dev/sdb` becomes `E` which is not what I want.
Is there a way to specify which drive should go in which position using kvm parameters?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like the point is to clean out all the drive mappings inside the:

```
\HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\MountedDevices
```

If windows does not find any previous mappings inside this reg key it maps devices in the same order as those are presented by the KVM.